# Access Java values in a custom widget, from erb template in Sonar

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

Is it possible to access Java values declared in a custom Widget class, from an erb template using the sonar api.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHen you say Java values, do you mean attributes of the widget instance? If so, then it's not possible.

However, there are the @WidgetProperties and @WidgetProperty annotation (see [1]) that allow you define widget properties (with default values if you want) that a user will be able to customize. And in your Ruby template, you'll be able to access them with the syntax "widget_properties['the_property_name']" (see [2]).

[1] https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/blob/master/plugins/sonar-core-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/core/widgets/TimelineWidget.java

[2] https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/blob/master/plugins/sonar-core-plugin/src/main/resources/org/sonar/plugins/core/widgets/timeline.html.erb